# How to get the bounding box from a DbGeography MULTIPOINT?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, spatial

Sorry if the question is not 100% related to SQL Server itself. But I thought it matches the topic close enough to post it here.

I'm using Entity Framework in my ASP.NET Web API project. While creating my POCOs I receive LatLngBounds from the browser client (Google Maps API).

I create a DbGeography (MULTIPOINT) instance from these incoming coordinates that represents my two points to re-create a rectangle.

Now I need the bounding box (polygon) of this MULTIPOINT construct. After some research I thought the STEnvelope function from the SqlGeometry assembly might help on this as I can not find a way to do this with the DbGeography type. Everything looks fine in the code until I try so save the object.

Please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e3b413278f2404512e4) for example code an the error message from EF. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a85ba26c0ffde3c7625e) for the generated SQL from EF.

Does it make sense to try it this way, or am I missing something important here and there's a much easier way?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static Tuple<double, double, double, double> GetEnvelopeFromPolygon(DbGeography polygon)
    {
        if (polygon == null)
        {
            return new Tuple<double, double, double, double>(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        var points = polygon.GetPointsFromPolygon();
        double minLat = double.MaxValue;
        double maxLat = double.MinValue;
        double minLon = double.MaxValue;
        double maxLon = double.MinValue;

        foreach (Tuple<double, double> point in points)
        {
            double lat = point.Item1;
            double lon = point.Item2;
            if (lat < minLat)
            {
                minLat = lat;
            }
            if (lat > maxLat)
            {
                maxLat = lat;
            }
            if (lon < minLon)
            {
                minLon = lon;
            }
            if (lon > maxLon)
            {
                maxLon = lon;
            }

        }

        var res = new Tuple<double, double, double, double>(minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon);
        return res;
    }


  public static IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> GetPointsFromPolygon(this System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography geo)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < geo.PointCount; i++)
        {
            var p = geo.PointAt(i);
            yield return new Tuple<double, double>(p.Latitude.Value, p.Longitude.Value);
        }

        var pFinal = geo.PointAt(1);
        yield return new Tuple<double, double>(pFinal.Latitude.Value, pFinal.Longitude.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Made it work. But still not sure if this is the way to go without complications. But at least storing the objects works by changing

```
poi.Shape = DbGeography.FromGml(envelop.AsGml().Value);
```

to

```
poi.Shape = DbGeography.FromText(envelop.ToString());
```

Leaving the question open as maybe someone else could provide a better solution.